# conditions for the existence of complex roots:

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, polynomials

find the necessary conditions under which the following polynomial will have non-real roots:
$P(x)=Ax^3+Bx^2+x-D$ where $A>0$ and $D>0$.

well if it has a+ib and a-ib as conjugate root then the polyomial can be written as ( $(x^2-2ax+a^2+b^2)(x-c)$) where c is a certain real root that follows from the long division.
the aim of this problem is finding under what conditions of the coefficients we will or will not have complex conjugate roots.

the remainder from the division needs to equal zero and that will lead us to a system of two equations involving$ a,a^2,b^2,$ and the rest of the coefficients and then things get a bit complicated you may find some necessary conditions but not all.if someone have a better strategy it will be appreciated.
you may also consider descarte's rule of signs but i am not sure if that will be sufficient.

Comment: What did you attempt so far? We are keen on helping so that you understand, not giving out solutions.

Comment: If a polynomial has real coefficients, then complex roots come in conjugate pairs.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\alpha$ be the real root of P. Then applying polynomial long division on P(x).. will produce the equation

$P(x) = (x-\alpha)(Ax^2 +(B+A\alpha)x + (1+B\alpha + A\alpha^2))$

with remainder $\alpha+B\alpha^2 + A\alpha^3 -D$. Since $\alpha$ is a root of $P$, $\alpha+B\alpha^2 + A\alpha^3 = D$. If $A,B,C$ are real, then if $P(x)$ has a complex root, it will occur in when the discriminant of the quadratic

$$(Ax^2 + (B+A\alpha)x +(1+B\alpha + A\alpha^2))$$
is negative. Hence we have the conditions

$(B+A\alpha)^2 - 4A(1+B\alpha+ A\alpha^2)<0$ and $D = \alpha+B\alpha^2 + A\alpha^3$.

Comment: your conditions are based on a certain $\alpha$ which is unknown. we need conditions on the coefficients only.

Comment: if you want to use the long division strategy then it is better to divide by$(x^2-2ax+a^2+b^2)$